# How to subtract query in knex.raw in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have done this query in mysql, but I don't know how to do this in knex.raw.

```
    select ((select leave_trackers.available_leaves from leave_trackers) -
(SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2018-06-11', '2018-06-01') + 1) - 
(WEEK('2018-06-11') - WEEK('2018-06-01')) -
(case when weekday('2018-06-11') = 6 then 1 else 0 end) -
(SELECT IFNULL(sum(total), 0)
from
(
select count(holidays.date) as total
FROM holidays, leave_applications 
WHERE holidays.date between '2018-06-01' and '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY holiday_id) as holiday_leave 
)
) as available_leaves
FROM leaves
group by leave_id
));
```

Can someone help me to convert this into knex.raw?

Answer (score 1):

```
knex.raw(`
select ((select leave_trackers.available_leaves from leave_trackers) -
(SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2018-06-11', '2018-06-01') + 1) - 
(WEEK('2018-06-11') - WEEK('2018-06-01')) -
(case when weekday('2018-06-11') = 6 then 1 else 0 end) -
(SELECT IFNULL(sum(total), 0)
from
(
select count(holidays.date) as total
FROM holidays, leave_applications 
WHERE holidays.date between '2018-06-01' and '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY holiday_id) as holiday_leave 
)
) as available_leaves
FROM leaves
group by leave_id
))
`).then(res => console.log(res));
```

If that doesn't work we need more info about what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael but I don't get response from the query, I think the problem is with subtracting the queries in between, knex.raw is not accepting it

Comment: @akshara In that case that query shouldn't work in SQL shell either. You need to add some code here for building your schema / populate database. Does any other query work? If they does you can strip down parts from your query to isolate the exact place which has the problem.

Comment: Yeah I have done the query separately like ```(DATEDIFF('2018-06-11', '2018-06-01') + 1)``` and other things, its working fine but when I subtract query its not working, that was my problem :-( @Mikael

Comment: Thanks! @Mikael I found the answer and posted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this :-),

```
knex.raw('((select leave_trackers.available_leave_days from leave_trackers) - (select ((DATEDIFF(?, ?) + 1) - (WEEK(?) - WEEK(?)) - (case when weekday(?) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) - (SELECT IFNULL(sum(total), 0) from (select count(holidays.date) as total FROM holidays WHERE holidays.date between ? and ? && holidays.location_id = ?) as holiday_leave )) AS total_available_days)) AS total_available_leave_days',
                                        ['2018-06-11', '2018-06-01', '2018-06-11', '2018-06-01', '2018-06-11', '2018-06-01', '2018-06-11', '1']
                                    )
```